# Running docker integration test containers while dev containers running

Tags: testing, docker, integration-testing, docker-compose

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
dev:
    docker-compose up -d --build

test:
    DOCKER_ENV="-test" docker-compose up -d --build
    // run some integration tests on the containers then
    // shut them down (and let ephemeral database disappear)
    DOCKER_ENV="-test" docker-compose down -v
```

And my docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:
  foo:
    container_name: foo${DOCKER_ENV}
    image: foo:latest
  bar:
    container_name: bar${DOCKER_ENV}
    image: bar:latest
```

When I try to run `make dev` and then `make test` the latter causes the dev containers to be rebuilt with the new name ("-test") rather than create an entire separate set of containers—which is what I want.

How can I keep the dev environment running and periodically spin up the test environment? (We'll do this on CI at some point, but I want developers to be able to locally run all the tests.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the docker-compose project name to separate dev from test, e.g.:

```
dev:
    docker-compose up -d --build

test:
    export DOCKER_PROJ=`basename \`pwd\``"-test"
    docker-compose -p ${DOCKER_PROJ} up -d --build
    // run some integration tests on the containers then
    // shut them down (and let ephemeral database disappear)
    docker-compose -p ${DOCKER_PROJ} down -v
```

(My Makefile syntax is a little rusty, I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do that.)

Comment: You can also set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` env variable instead of using `-p`.